# Hiding nodes performance

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When hiding nodes, the performance seems to slow down quite a lot with larger IFC HVAC models (80000 nodes and upwards). On a standard computer this takes almost 10 seconds. I have two models and want to hide one of them. Currently this is done with rootId. Is there any modifications to be made to make this faster? What would be the fastest way to hide all the nodes?

```
var vm = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VisibilityManager(viewer.impl, viewer.model);
var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
var rootId = instanceTree.getRootId();
vm.hide(rootId);
vm.setNodeOff(rootId, true);
```

When showing parts of the same file, with few thousand nodes this seems to be quite a bit faster. Eventhough the nodes are shown one by one.

```
var totalNodes = nodesToIsolate.length;
for (var i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++) {                          
   vm.show(nodesToIsolate[i]);
   vm.setNodeOff(nodesToIsolate[i], false); // True = hide completely                            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are saying that the second approach is quite faster than the first one... in that case what prevents you to use the second approach over the first? You could traverse the model structure from rootId to determine all the node and then use second approach, or am I missing something?

I am guessing that a faster approach would be to affect a custom ShaderMaterial to each fragment of the model and control the visibility from the shader code, however traversing the model to affect the material would also take time, but the operation could potentially be performed at an earlier stage.

Also you could completely unload the model from the scene with **viewer.impl.unloadModel(model)**, obviously if you need to restore it later it will take time.

Comment: Unloading the model will not work, because after hiding, we need to show part of the nodes. On average computer, on Chrome hiding 79658 nodes takes 5668 milliseconds. On Internet Explorer hiding the same amount of nodes takes 31514 milliseconds. Why is hiding on Internet Explorer so slow? Is there any tricks to speed this up? When hiding from rooId the performance on both browsers is not any faster than hiding the nodes one by one.
Is there a faster of hiding the model? It seems vm.hide(rootId) should be considerably faster than just hiding the nodes one by one?

Comment: If you look in the viewer3D.js source code, you will see that "viewer.hide" invokes "VisibilityManager.prototype.setVisibilityOnNode" and in order to hide a top level node, the code needs to go recursively down the children nodes, so it can ultimately be slower. I suppose a faster approach would be to hide only the leaf nodes, which are the ones that actually contain visible geometry. It can be faster especially in the case you have a deeply nested model structure.